# Failed to retrieve user profile using Search API by Birthday date filter after updating the Birthday property using Power shell

Tags: user-profile-service, user-profile-property, sharepoint-on-prem

I have updated an user profile Birthday date using Powershell
Birthday format(MMM DD) Eg: February 15.
here is my script

```
 $adAccount = "domain\username"
 $up = $profileManager.GetUserProfile($adAccount)
 $up["SPS-Birthday"].Value = "February 15"
 $up.Commit()
```

Now I have run the Incremental call in search service application.
after that I browse the search api to retrieve the results whose Birthday from "February 05" to "February 20"

see url below

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='Birthday>="02-05-2000" AND Birthday<="02-20-2000"'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&selectproperties='AccountName,FirstName,Birthday'
```

I am unable to retrieve the profile which I was updated through powershell shown above in search api results.

Please provide me solution for this...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below powershell:

```
$adAccount = "domain\username"
$up = $profileManager.GetUserProfile($adAccount)

$birthday = "February 15"
$birthdayDateValue = "{0:dd MMM}" -f [datetime]$birthday
$up["SPS-Birthday"].Value = $birthdayDateValue

$up.Commit()
```

Check if the value is updated in the user's profile via Central admin.

Map the `SPS-BirthDay` property to one of the `RefinableDate00` property as below (sorry for non-english screenshot) :

[image]

After that do a full crawl of the People content source.

Now modify your REST query as below:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&selectproperties='AccountName,FirstName,RefinableDate00'&refinementfilters='RefinableDate00:range(datetime(02-05-2000), datetime(02-20-2000), from=\"ge\", to=\"le\")'"
```

Reference - [Limit search results by exact time SP 2013](http://www.techmikael.com/2013/07/limiting-search-results-by-exact-time.html)

[show upcoming birthdays based on sharepoint 2013 user profiles](https://joranmarkx.wordpress.com/2013/10/02/show-upcomming-birthdays-based-on-sharepoint-2013-user-profiles-with-search-office365/)

Comment: Still the problem exists on search results I cannot see the profile which I updated through Powershell.

Comment: is the property correctly updated via powershell ? did you check it via central admin ?

Comment: can you check the edited answer ? also can you check if the property is actually updated in the user profile via central admin ?

Comment: Yes i have checked in central admin it is showing updated Birthday which I did through powershell.

Comment: I am not able to get results when I tried your rest API response in SharePoint Online. Is there any changes in endpoint over the time?

Answer (score 0):

Map the **SPS-Birthday** crawled property with one of the managed property and while searching, use Managed property name instead of Birthday.

refer the screen shot - i have mapped the **SPS-Birthday** property with **RefinableString00**

[image]

Comment: I tried this but it is not working when i use search api giving exception that we didn't understand you search term
/_api/search/query?querytext='RefinableString00>="02-05-2000" AND RefinableString00<="02-20-2000"'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&selectproperties='AccountName,FirstName,Birthday'

Comment: Try like that into your people search center -  RefinableString00:"MM/dd"  by default year is considered as 2000. in your search query also you have to build your string like this

Comment: Also make sure the User Profile property SPS-Birthday visibility set to everyone, if it is only me then search wont return any result..

Comment: I am allowed to search data and fetch all the profiles correctly, if I update the Birthday with "MM/DD/YYYY". If I update like "February 15" with out year I am unable to get it.

Comment: I am able to get the data the problem is when update only month and day it is taking by default current year not 2000 that why in my search query filter i am unable to see the data which is in 2000 year. If i keep current year i am able to search results.
Thanks for you response..!

Comment: Great, you got the result, For filtering i don't think year is required, that's why i have suggested to use  only month and day like this RefinableString00:"MM/dd". and thnaks for the useful information that it is taking current year not 2000. Thanks

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it helped you :)